# Can my code be parallelized with python multiprocess?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    content = input_file(target).split("\n")
    content = manager.list(content)
    for files in source:
        obj_grab.append((LogCatcher(files), content))
    pool = Pool()
    pool.map(transferConcat, obj_grab)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

def concatMessage(LogCatcher, content):
    for key in LogCatcher.dic_map:
        regex = re.compile(key)
        for j in range(len(content)):
            for m in re.finditer(regex, content[j]):
                content[j] += LogCatcher.index + LogCatcher.dic_map[key]

def transferConcat(args):
    return concatMessage(*args)
```

When I use `pool.map()`, it takes 82 secs to finish this code.

While I use normal for loop to run this code, it takes 11 secs.

It must be something wrong with pool.map() while I got the right output with these two methods.

Can my code be parallelized?

`obj_grab` is a list, which contains logCatchers with different file inputs. `content` is the list I want to concatenate, and I use `manager()` to let multiprocess concat the same list.

Comment: That might mean that the code is so simple that the added overhead of the pool causes in increase.

Comment: Actually, it looks like all you're doing with the pool is processing all of the concanting on a single other thread instead of the main thread. Look into the documentation for pool; you may need to split up the jobs, and give them to the pool 1 by 1.